# Dirac measure on periodic orbits for Hamiltonian Dynamcis

Tags: measure-theory, dirac-delta, hamilton-equations

An iterative map $T: x_{n+1} = T(x_n)$, given an initial state $x$, defines a periodic orbit:

$O_x=\lbrace x, S(x), ...,S^{n-1}(x) \rbrace$ ,

with $S^n(x) = x$.
The periodic orbit supports a measure defined by

$\delta_{O_x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \delta_{S^i(x)} $ ,

where $\delta_{S^i(x)})$ is the Dirac measure.
This definition is given in ref. [1] pag. 38.

> First of all, can we say that this measure corresponds to a uniform distribution?
>
> Secondly, how can be written for continuous dynamics like Hamiltonian dynamics?

I would write:

Given a Hamiltonian flow map $\Phi^t:\Phi^t(x(0)) \rightarrow x(t)$, with $x=\lbrace q,p \rbrace$, the closed orbit with period $T$ defined by
$O_x=\lbrace x, S^{\Delta t}(x), ...,S^T(x) \rbrace$ ,

where $\Delta t$ is a small timestep, supports the measure

$\delta_{O_x} = \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^T \delta(\Phi^t(x)) \mathrm{d}t$ .

Is this correct?

**References**
[1] [http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~mrasmuss/ergodictheory/ErgodicTheoryNotes.pdf](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/%7Emrasmuss/ergodictheory/ErgodicTheoryNotes.pdf) pag.38